# EF 4.1 to EF 4.3.1: Something is still referencing 4.1, but can't find it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

### Setup:

I have an app that is a copy of another app, that worked with EF 4.1.  In the new app, I have added a nuget package reference to EF 4.3.1 in a domain project.

All works on my local machine, but on the server throws the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Clearly, something is still referencing the old entity framework 4.1, but the only dll it finds is the EF 4.3.1 dll.

There are no references to EntityFramework in the web.config.

### Question:

How do I find what is still referencing the old dll?

I have removed all EF references from all projects in the solution and added the EF 4.3.1 package to each project, but still no joy.

### Notes:

I could try a binding redirect using the dependentAssembly (see accepted answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-the-wrong-referenced-assembly-version))

However, I can't find what names and tokens to use.

Still, it would be better to get to the route of the problem, rather than just redirecting a binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you recompiled the application after changing the reference, or just uploaded the new `EntityFramework.dll` file? It's possible the application's library is still referencing the old version in your production environment. Do a re-compile and re-publish.

**EDIT** (see comments) : Open all your .csproj files in notepad and look for the Reference tags, double check that the old version doesn't exist in all the projects.

Comment: Yes, I have recompiled and reloaded the dlls of the different projects.

Comment: Ok, open all your .csproj files in notepad and look for the Reference tags, double check that the old version doesn't exist in all the projects.

Comment: I finally found the rogue reference.  Despite having removed it, it rehydrated for reasons that escape me.  Checking through each project file set me in motion.  Thanks.  +1 and have accepted answer.  You might add an EDIT to your answer so that it truly reflects the solution to the problem...?