# VS 2010, adding a reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices 12.0.2000.8 (SQL server 2014) shows as 10.0.0 in .csproj

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, sql-server-2014

I'm currently upgrading one of my projects which has Microsoft.AnalysisServices version 9.0.242.0 to version 12.0.2000.8 as a part of supporting SQL Server 2014. I have copied the Microsoft.AnalysisServices (12.0.2000.8) from Sql Server 2014 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies). I removed the old assembly reference in the project and added the new assembly (12.0.2000.8). When I open the csproj in text editor I found the version number as 10.0.0

```
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\3Party\Microsoft Analysis Services\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DLL</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Version information from the Debug> Modules window shown below

[image]

I'm doing this on VS2010, I want know

- Why is the version number in the csproj set to 10.0.0 even though I have added the assembly whose version is 12.0.2000.8
- Is it fine if I leave this as 10.0.0 ?
- What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Good question, when you run the app can you tell us which version of the DLL is being loaded? Use Visual Studios Module Window to see - it's Debug Menu > Windows > Modules

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have updated the information in the description above. It loads the 12.0.2000.8 dll

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate folder for Referenced dll(Inside your project) and copy the required version there and then use it as a reference dll. Make sure to delete bin and obj folder before you build the project

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version) has some information similar to your issue.

Comment: I already have it in a separate folder and am doing all that you started. My question is more on why is the version number inconsistent.

Comment: Looks like OP is doing something similar with the 3Party folder specified in the hint path

Comment: In the refrence you added go to its properties and set this property SpecificVersion to True

Comment: and also make sure the version of dll that you have placed in 3Party\Microsoft Analysis Services

Comment: @Syeda that is not what I'm looking for.