# Version conflict in a Visual Studio copied project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, conflict, mismatch

I have a Visual Studio solution which is running fine. I have copied a few projects from this and put in a new solution. When i try to run in one of the calls it gives me an error that a dll is missing.

I confirmed the existence of the dll in the project which is holding the reference to this other project, on further inspection, i observed the version number of the dll in the error message is not matching the version number of the dll that i had copied.

What might have gone wrong in my copy the project?

Please let me know if my question is at very high level? I will put in required details as you may need.

Comment: what is the specific error? this is sherlock

Answer (score 0):

i understand error.refer the follwing link and go through the comments ,u will definetly got the answer.

[.Net picking wrong referenced assembly version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version)

Answer (score 0):

OK, i showed this error to my technical lead and here was his finding -

it was because of another project which was being referenced in my main project. This another project was having a reference of this dll too. This another project was of the version number which i was getting an error of.
My TL told me that since this another project was compiling of different version number, it was expecting my dll to be also of the same version.

Over here, i have used the term another project for convenience of understanding only. It is not "another project" but another dll instead which is internally referring to the dll which i was also using in my main project. It seemed that these dlls should both have been of same version for running correctly.

I found and copied this dll from my colleagues machine and referred it in my main project and got through with this problem.

To identify this dll also -
We ran the old code and new code and with help of ProcMon my TL concluded the version conflict of this another dll