# Azure server throwing exception after certain numbers of API call

Tags: c#, linq, sockets, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I have created an API (MVC) and Hosted it in Azure server. The API is receiving an 1 Image and 1 Text at a time. It is working properly for the single call or first call but after certain numbers of API call getting below error.

**After installing `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` :**

Error:

> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/Project/002 MVC API/Cherish/API/Cherish.Api/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = D:\Project\002 MVC API\Cherish\API\Cherish.Api\bin
>   Calling assembly : Cherish.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Project\002 MVC
>   API\Cherish\API\Cherish.Api\web.config LOG: Using host configuration
>   file: C:\Users\Yudiz\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,
>   Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Yudiz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/7b6de7f7/4f48effb/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Yudiz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/7b6de7f7/4f48effb/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Project/002 MVC
>   API/Cherish/API/Cherish.Api/bin/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major
>   Version ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var blobHelper = new BlobHelper();
var response = new UploadMediaResponse();
for (var i = 0; i<provider.Files.Count; i++)
{
    Guid itemId;
    var fileData = await provider.Files[i].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    if (mediaType == MediaType.Thumbnail)
    {
        // MediaId is mandatory for Audio & Video media
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider.FormData["mediaId"]))
        // ReSharper disable once NotResolvedInText
            return ErrorResponse(new ArgumentNullException("mediaId", "MediaId was not provided"));
        itemId = new Guid(provider.FormData["mediaId"]);
        await blobHelper.Upload(mediaType, accountId, itemId, fileData, timelineEvent.ChildId);
        var mediaItem = timelineEvent.Media.Single(m => m.Id == itemId);
        mediaItem.HasThumbnail = true;
        mediaItem.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        await timelineEventRepository.UpdateAsync(timelineEvent, entityDoc.SelfLink);
    }
    else
    {
        itemId = await blobHelper.Upload(mediaType, accountId, fileData, timelineEvent.ChildId);
        var mediaItem = new TimelineMediaItem
        {
            Id = itemId,
            Available = true,
            FileSize = fileData.Length,
            Removed = false,
            Type = mediaType.ToUpper(),
            TaggedChildren = new List<TaggedChild>(),
            Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
            LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
        if (fileLengthsRequired)
            mediaItem.Length = fileLengths[i];
        timelineEvent.Media.Add(mediaItem);
        await timelineEventRepository.UpdateAsync(timelineEvent, entityDoc.SelfLink);
    }
    response.MediaIds.Add(itemId);
}
```

Declaration for DocumentClient:

```
public DocumentRepository()
{
    Client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbEndpointUrl"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbAuthKey"]);
    DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbDatabaseName"];
    PageSize = Int16.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);
    var _database = ReadOrCreateDatabase();
    var collection = InitialiseCollection(_database.SelfLink, EntityName);
    DocumentsLink = collection.DocumentsLink;
    SelfLink = collection.SelfLink;
}
```

Here is my error:

> Error String :=> Optional({"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"One or more errors
>   occurred.","ExceptionType":"System.AggregateException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.get_Result()\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery1.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>
> at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source)\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)\r\n at
>   Cherish.Domain.Repositories.Implementation.DocumentRepository1.ReadOrCreateDatabase()\r\n
>   at
>   Cherish.Domain.Repositories.Implementation.DocumentRepository1..ctor()\r\n
>   at Cherish.Api.Helpers.BlobHelper.AccountHasEnoughStorageCapacity(Guid
>   accountId, Int32 fileSize)\r\n at
>   Cherish.Api.Helpers.BlobHelper.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack
>   trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at Cherish.Api.Helpers.BlobHelper.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n
>   at Cherish.Api.Controllers.TimelineController.d__15.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   Cherish.Api.Controllers.TimelineController.d__11.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while
>   sending the
>   request.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility1.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryExecutionContext.d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery1.d__10.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to connect to the
>   remote
>   server","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":" at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An attempt was made to access a socket
>   in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean
>   flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)"}}}})

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you using Azure DocumentDB? I found a issue about the similar error, you could refer to [it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ddee231-d8f3-451f-8c94-954205ba02fc/azure-documentdb-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-serveran-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket?forum=AzureDocumentDB). Would you please provide your core code snippet for us to locate this issue?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT Yes, I am using DocumentDB and I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT : did you get the chance to check the above question please ?

Comment: From the stacktrace, I noticed that the error was thrown at `DocumentRepository.ReadOrCreateDatabase()`. Based on your code, what does the variable `timelineEventRepository` represent for, the `DocumentRepository` class or something else? Have you tried to 
 implement the singleton (e.g. creating a static instance of DocumentClient and reusing that static instance) for `DocumentClient` within the `DocumentRepository` class?

Comment: `timelineEventRepository` is `DocumentRepository`. `singleton` you mean I have to define `DocumentClient` outside the `constructor` as a `Static Member`? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your issue, I assumed that there be connection issues between your client and documentdb endpoint after certain numbers of API call. You could try to create a static instance of `DocumentClient` and add the retry policy to your `DocumentRepository` class as follows:

```
public class DocumentRepository
{
    private static readonly DocumentClient _client;
    static DocumentRepository()
    {
        var connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 5,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 5
            }
        };
        _client = new DocumentClient(
            new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbEndpointUrl"]),
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbAuthKey"],
            connectionPolicy);
    }

    public DocumentRepository()
    {
        DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbDatabaseName"];
        PageSize = Int16.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);
        var _database = ReadOrCreateDatabase();
        var collection = InitialiseCollection(_database.SelfLink, EntityName);
        DocumentsLink = collection.DocumentsLink;
        SelfLink = collection.SelfLink;
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(TimelineEvent timelineEvent, string selfLink)
    {
        //TODO:
        await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync("{documentCollectionUri}", timelineEvent);
    }
}
```

Additionally, there is a official [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/documentdb/2015/01/14/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1/) talking about performance tips for Azure DocumentDB, you could refer to it.

Comment: I am getting error while using `RetryOptions` : `'ConnectionPolicy' does not contain a definition for 'RetryOptions'`

Comment: I used [Microsoft Azure DocumentDB Client Library 1.11.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB) in my development, you could try to check the version of your client library. Any concerns, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am using `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client`

Comment: I have added `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` and the error is gone now. now I am testing the real issue.

Comment: Should I dispose `DocumentClient` ?

Comment: It is recommended to use a single instance of `DocumentClient` per AppDomain for the lifetime of your application. You could firstly check whether this issue could be solved.

Comment: I assumed that since you have updated the version of `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB`, there my be old version reside in your other projects references. You could refer to this similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137978/discussion-between-chandresh-khambhayata-and-bruce-msft).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is actually not the solution to the issue above.  Adding the retry info does hide some of the symptoms but it doesn't prevent it from happening again in the future.

If the `DocumentClient` is not properly defined AS A `Singleton` then its possible the application will run out of `TCP connections` and that's when you get the `socket error`.

Please refer to
 [this link on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ddee231-d8f3-451f-8c94-954205ba02fc/azure-documentdb-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-serveran-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket?forum=azurecosmosdb) for a little more information.

Thanks and I hope this helps others.

Comment: This should be a comment.