# .Net application with crystal report not working in shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have a MVC application that uses crystal report. I have used the following code to download the report,

```
 ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
 rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/" + Session["rpt"])));
 rd.SetDataSource(Session["result"]);
 Response.Buffer = false;
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 //Excel
 Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel);
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 return File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Cheque.xls");
```

Report downloading working fine in localhost. But when I have hosted this application in Godaddy's shared hosting, gives the following screen
[image]

Comment: The error is clear that it is missing the required log4net dll reference somewhere.

Comment: @Souvik Ghosh I have added log4net dll reference. But giving the same result. I think problem is because of shared hosting.

Comment: i too had the same problem, it works fine in localhost but giving the above error in godaddy shared hosting @AbhilashRavindranCK

Comment: This is because of assembly version mismatched

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Godaddy's shared hosting do not support Crystal report.
Not only Godaddy's shared hosting but also most of the host provider's shared hosting do not support
Crystal reports. To use Crystal report you have to purchase VPS or Dedicated Server.

If you want to run Crystal report on the server, it's always need the Crystal report runtime on that server.
GoDaddy's shared hosting servers use the default Medium trust level that do not support the
insatllation of Crystal report runtime.

**Useful Information :**

> GoDaddy's shared hosting servers **use the default Medium
> trust level with the addition of OleDbPermission,  OdbcPermission, and
> a less-restrictive WebPermission.**
>
> Applications operating under a
> Medium trust level **have no registry access, no access to the Windows
> event log, and  cannot use reflection.** Such applications can
> communicate only with a defined range of network addresses and file
> system  access is limited to the application's virtual directory
> hierarchy. Please make sure that your application can work in a
> Medium trust environment if you are having any problems with it.

So people can use this as an indication of what shared hosting permissions are generally like.

One of the shared hosting that support Crystal Report is http://asphostportal.com. I am not sure about this.
I got this information from other communities.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of log4net assembly version mismatched. See this
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version)

Comment: Already tried adding <dependentAssembly> tag. Still getting same error. Adding this tag has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have double confirmed this with Godaddy shared hosting and they only support Crystal reports on dedicated servers or VPS as of April 2021.