# SendGrid.SmtpAPI Upgrade from 1.3.1 to 1.3.3

Tags: .net, nuget, sendgrid

We are using SendGrid v.6.1.0 and SendGrid.SmptpApi v.1.3.1 in our .NET project.

I upgraded SendGrid.SmptpApi to v.1.3.3 using NuGET. Solution builds however under debug (and in production) it throws an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid.SmtpApi, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2ae73662c35d80e4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"SendGrid.SmtpApi, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2ae73662c35d80e4"}

Here is all remedies I have tried:

1. reset IIS, recursively remove all **obj** and **bin** folders from solution.
2. removed content of "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder
3. Added

[image]

to web.config as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version)

4. Removed and restored all NuGET packages.
5. Reinstalled .NET
6. Searched solution folder for any mentioning of 1.3.1 (no results)

I am still getting this exception and I am out of ideas how to remove any references to SendGrid.SmtpAPI. v.1.3.1

Please help.

Comment: do you have a transient dependency  on it?

Comment: how can I verify?