# Could not load file or assembly - Publish solution got assembly with wrong version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using C#, .NET CORE 3.1, Visual Studio 2019.

The source solution contains many projects which using jenkins for build by command:

```
dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.1 -r win-x86 --self-contained false /p:AssemblyVersion=\"1.1.1.1\" /p:Version=\"1.1.1.1\" /p:FileVersion=\"1.1.1.1\" -c release MySolutionFile.sln -o sln_build/MyProductBuild/win_x86"
```

I have to say in past months it works great, until days ago, I pull down a build artifacts and run it, an error was thrown:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
> Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (0x80131040)

I looked the file `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` in artifacts folder, the `File Version` was showing `2.2.0.18315`, obvious this is a wrong version, the expecting one should be with version `5.0.0.0`.

Then I'm trying to locate which project referenced this wrong version:

- I searched `*.csproj` and `*.deps.json` for each projects under the solution, could not see any project referened the wrong version, all referenced to `5.0.0.0`.
- Delete all `obj` and `bin` folder under each projects, and then re-publish, still no luck.

Any suggestions?

**[edit0]**

- Multiple .NET CORE SDKs installed on this build machine:

> .NET SDKs installed:
> 2.1.811 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.2.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 3.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

- the `packages` in my build machine is located at:

> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages

I removed the folder: `microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection` and `microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions`.

- after a new build, can see the above folders were created again and filled with different version of this assembly, include version `2.2` and `5.0` and others.
- after a new build, the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` in each project's bin folder is with **correct** version, that means only the **solution output** folder get the wrong version.

Comment: Please try the following suggestions: 
1.Right click on reference -> properties -> change 'Specific Version' to false.
2.Cleaning old versions installed at C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\

Comment: @DanielZhang-MSFT I can't see the `Specific Version` option in my VS(Eneterprise 2019 Version 16.11.2).    I cleared the `packages` (as my edit explained) folder but seems no impact.

Comment: Right click on the specific reference in the References directory.
And please try to put in a binding redirect in your web.config file like this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version

Comment: the `binding redirect` may a way to fix this(though .NET CORE seems not directly support), I still want to know where exactly this `wrong reference` come from. thanks.

Comment: Please check your Global Assembly Cache in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac