# Azure-Devops Pipeline: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

After adding a reference to 3d party I started keep getting an error:
`Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

In my proj file I'm using 13 version.

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Locally I fixed this error with: `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json`

On Azure-Devops CI Nuget restore step look like this:
[image]

On Job log is see that this package is restoring:

```
Restoring NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1
```

I tried `Disable local cache option`, it doesn't work.

How I should specify this step to force reinstall nuget package?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Yes, bindingRedirect on config and restore on DevOps Pipline resolved this issue. Marked as resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is typically fixed by defining bindingRedirect in your web.config (or app.config) file(s).

Please check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version).

Comment: Yes, bindingRedirect on config and restore on DevOps Pipline resolved this issue. Thank you.