# What causes this error and how to solve it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, reference

hi
I have delivered a vb.net solution which contains 3 projects (Biz, Data Access, Presentation).
Recently, when I compile it, I get the following error:

"The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference(Exception from HResult.....)" 
When I double click on it, unfortunately it says to me that "The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved"

**How can I solve it?**  I should say that did several things such as "Clean solution, rebuild it"   but it didn't work.

What's your suggestion?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this post on StackOverflow: [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

I believe it answers the same question you present here.

Answer (score 0):

It means one of the assemblies referenced in  your project cannot be located. It has located the assembly but it doesn't fully match it, for ex either the version, culture or public key token is different.