# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, controls, telerik

I am working on a project in asp.net using Telerik Controls.
Everytime when i run my project i am getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design,
>   Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
>   assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

But when I refresh the page, its working fine. Why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the manifest definition of the assembly file doesn't match the actual reference.

See here for more info:

> [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215026/441574)
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/03/25/95826.aspx

You could try changing the reference version from `Version=3.1.0.0` to `Version=3.1.0.1`, or another version if you might know it.

Comment: Can you please tell how to get Public key token value.pls help

Comment: Changing `Version=3.1.0.1` and `PublicKeyToken=null` worked for me. Thanks!