# Strange error every second build Facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I keep getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook, Version=5.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: check your project's `.NET Framework` version and the version of Facebook binary it was build with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem once when there were two different assembly versions available and when the assemblies were copied across projects with some inconsistently set assembly references. The versions got mixed up and the error appeared.

But take a look a this and links provided there, it should give you some suggestions or ideas:
[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: Thanks. I feel really stupid. I had a reference to an old version inside another project which it shouldn't have been there.