# Reference conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube

I have added a references to the following dll's to my website

**Google.GData.Client.dll

Google.GData.YouTube.dll

Google.GData.Extensions.dll**

they are used for uploading video to youtube. Now when I try to compile my website it adds another dll called Newtonsoft.Json.dll and compilation fails with

> Error 4   The type 'System.Func' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' and 'g:\Projects\X\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'

I can't believe that google has released a product with such a bug, I must be missing something here?

Does any one know how to workaround this issue?

Comment: maybe you should use dll version for the .net 3/4 ?

Comment: have you seen [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/detail?id=589)? It includes a possible workaround.

Comment: recompile your application as a .NET 3.5 version opposed to 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by dowloading the 4.0 version of the Newtonsoft.Json.dll from http://json.codeplex.com/.

Google seems to distribute only the 2.0 version.

Comment: This is still acurate in 2012. I replaced the Newtonsoft.Json.dll with the apropiate .net version and all was good.

Comment: I fixed this within VS by updating the NuGet package

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Now it compiles, but when I run it, it crashes at the first Google API call, [complaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026) about the Newtonsoft.Json version...