# MySql.Data.dll version in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql

I have an ASP.Net / c# web application running under framework 4.0, for some years now, using MySQL database.

I have recently being trying to implement reports, and have been trying to use for the first time the automated dataset wizard to create a new DataTable adapter. In running the wizard, I am able to set the datatable adapter and configure the sql statement. I am even able to execute and test it from the visual studio designer. I am also able to create a connection from the Server Explorer tab in Visual Studio and browse the database schema.

When I next try to compile the application, I get the following error:

> "Error    1   Failed to generate code. Could not load file or assembly
>   'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)   C:\Projects\Sharpview
>   V2\SharpView V2\App_Code\MCPS\DAL\dsCrewHistory.xsd   1"

Looking in my bin directory, the version I have is 6.4.3.0. Does this mean that I have to download  MySQL.Data.dll version 6.6.5.0 and replace it in the bin file? Where can I download this version?

Answer (score 1):

In the visual studio take the reference from the explorer and make sure that the `Specific Version` is set to `false`.

If you have an acces to the file `web.config` make changes to the file and remove version info.

You would need to open the project file with you fav text editor and make sure the version is not mentioned , then remove the  line

`, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'`

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914801/asp-server-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-but-the-assembly-is-definit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882217/mysql-connector-6-7-4-and-entity-framework-5-exceptions)

Comment: hi thanks for your response. how do I set the Specific Version to false? where do I click to set that? My dll is in the bin directory.

Comment: you would need to check reference...please have a look at the link i have given....please acept the answer if helps.

Comment: maaaan... thanks a lot!!! You saved me from more than 2 hours of struggling with this issue!! :( Really appreciate it!! This should be marked as answer!! Thanks again...