# Error while creating pdf using iTextsharp.dll

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

Error Occurs while running **C#** project, which uses **itextsharp.dll** to genereate pdf file

The content of error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you added the iTextsharp dll in the namespace ? If yes then is it giving error line there ?

Comment: yes i added dll to reference and also included that namespace too.

Comment: so exactly where you are getting the error ? In consuming the classes from dll or in the namespace addition ?

Comment: As googled its seen to be dll not loaded properly.                      Error raised at program.cs page, in 'Application.Run(new Form1());'

Comment: Thanks for ur replies, error got fixed, i am using appconfig file in my project,in that there was a tag named <runtime> i removed that, which was genreated by .net while including dll

Answer (score 1):

Check first, whether the referenced version in your solution matches 5.4.1.0.
You could try to select the reference in the project References folder and set "Specific Version" to false.

For further hints, see [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Answer (score 0):

you have to paste the following 4 files

```
 itextsharp.dll,
 itextsharp.pdfa.dll,
 itextsharp.xml,
 itextsharp.xtra.dll
```

in current folder, from where you are executing your .exe file.