# EPplus assembly error

Tags: asp.net, .net, epplus

I am using asp.net 4.5 framework. I just downloaded EPPLus using NUget Package. I then used the code given at the following link.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

And add following code on click event of a button. After clicking the button, i am getting following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'EPPlus, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Please suggest If I am making any stupid mistake.

[image]

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //Create the worksheet
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

    //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

    //Format the header for column 1-3
    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:C1"])
    {
        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;                      //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));  //Set color to dark blue
        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
    }


    //Write it back to the client
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

Comment: is the assembly installed in the gac or in the site bin?

Comment: Aseembly is not installed in GAC for sure. What do you mean by site bin. Did you mean bin folder of the application?

Comment: yes that is what i mean.

Comment: @DanielA.White is pointing on the right direction!
I caught in the same error and got solution! https://stackoverflow.com/a/77013128/6836199

Answer (score 5):

I met a case where my solution was prepared for test purposes and consisted of several projects which had reference to EPPlus. The problem was I referenced ver 4 to only one project and I left others with older version of EPPlus (esp. the executable one had older ver). The result was that after build process the folder contained older EPPlus and during the run-time I used linked project with newer EPPlus (so the project was not able to find proper version of EPPlus).
After I referenced the same version of EPPlus to all projects, the exception was not thrown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This part

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

Suggests that the version number of the assembly isn't matching the version number in your config file.
 See this question:[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: Thank you reply. I am not sure why I am running into this problem. I downloaded the assembly using NUGet package. And there is no compile time error. Not sure if the code i am using is looking for older version of assembly. But in that case I should have got compile time error.