# Error in reporting using SSRS against SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I am getting the following error when running a report against a SQL Server database - any ideas?

Thanks

> An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Seems your SSRS is not installed properly.If possible reinstall it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSRS as a client file (`.rdlc`) in your web or Windows app, you need the following assemblies:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

Download the assemblies via NuGet:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/

Also make sure that the entry for this is backward compatible in the `web.config` configuration.
In your references folder; right-click and set `copy local = true`.