# Could not load file or assembly using WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, plsqldeveloper

using:
- windows app - visual studio - 2008
- back end -oracle 11G
- web service - visual studio - 2010
- IIS(Application pools >> Advanced Settings >> Enable 32bit Applications is enabled)

I created a windows application using WCF service. When I host the service in my local machine(Using IIS) it works fine. When hosted on server, it shows an error:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=10.2.0.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference.*

Help me to solve the problem

Comment: Can you please reformat your questoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following,

1. Check the `version` of the dll you have placed and the version you application has reference to.
2. First check if you have installed `Oracle client(ODAC)` in the web server. Without oracle client your application will not load the assembly.
3. If it has Oracle client installed then check whether its `32 or 64 bit` and your application should have reference to same bit version of the assembly.
4. Also IIS `32bit Enabled` property should match the Oracle DataAccess dll your application referencing. (*Basically processor architecture of Oracle Client installation in the server, Oracle.DataAccess dll and IIS enabled bit version should be same. either 32 or 64*)
5. Check the `GAC` and remove if there is any other Oracle DataAccess dlls.

Comment: Trying to remove Oracle.DataAccess from GAC it says Access Denied.

Comment: @Gandarez How are you trying to remove the dll from GAC ? you would need admin privilege to install/remove from GAC.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your server has a different version of the Oracle.DataAccess assembly installed in the GAC.  Are you able to confirm what version is installed on the server?

Also, see this previous question:
[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: change the Oracle Data Access version it works fine... thanks