# EnterpriseLibrary issue on live server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, enterprise-library

After configuring my application in client's System, I am facing following issue.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have placed all required Dlls in system.
but when I click ctrl + F5 when I get error, it works fine.

I cant figure out what is issue.
hence this is first time I am deploying application on client machine. (is there anything that need to install for Enterpriselib use on fresh system. It has .net 4.0 installed)

```
<body>
Line 74:     <form id="form1" runat="server">
Line 75:     **<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">**
Line 76:     </asp:ScriptManager>
Line 77:     <div id="main">
```

it shows line75 as error.

can anyone suggest what issue is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the enterprise library was installed on the computer the .dll's are installed in the GAC, if you are asking for a different version in your web.config file than what is found in the GAC a version mismatch can occur. Verify that the local copies of the .dll's that you want to use are in the web sites bin directory.

Verify what is in the global cache GAC with gacutil /l note that either visual studio or the windows sdk must be installed on the system for the utility to be present. See **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx**

Also see
**[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)**