# OAuth.dll using higher version than referenced assembly of webMatrix.data and webmatrix.webdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, web-config, webmatrix, nuget-package

I am getting this error:

```
Assembly 'Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'WebMatrix.WebData, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version 
than referenced assembly 'WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

1. I have followed this post [Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407124/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webmatrix-data) from the stack overflow and installed it

   PM> Install-Package WebMatrix.Data but not working.
2. then i deleted packages folder and restore it that also not working.
3. I tried the following:

   PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
   then installed it again.that's also not working.

First thing notice able, if I tried to install the nuget packages seperately----

```
 PM> Install-Package WebMatrix.WebData
```

and

```
PM> Install-Package WebMatrix.Data
```

Then its providing me only this vrsion 2.0.30506

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this issue. The web.config file is something like this.

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" /> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error CS1705: "which has a higher version than referenced assembly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219832/error-cs1705-which-has-a-higher-version-than-referenced-assembly)

Comment: I have tried this http://robertgreiner.com/2014/06/assembly-uses-version-which-has-a-higher-version-than-referenced-assembly-error/ But problem is not fully gone.Now, its stating following message---------Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. No luck with a solution?

I don't understand how the OAuth package could be using WebMatrix.WebData version 3 because this version just doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Nuget listing for **WebMatrix.WebData** and **WebMatrix.Data**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMatrix.Data/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMatrix.WebData/

notice that they were

> ***last updated*** on ***Friday, May 31, 2013***

These assemblies were moved into

**Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages Data 3.2.3**
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data/

**Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages Web Data 3.2.3**
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData/

Because the names of the assembly names have remained the same, but the locations have changes, Nuget Package Manager gets confused -- failing to correctly add / remove the references from your project.

---

### What to do?

- in **references**, remove any reference to `WebPages.Data` and/or `WebPages.WebData`
- in package manager, run

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData`

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data`

- in your **Web Project**, right click on "references" -> click "Add reference" -> click "Browse..."  navigate in your packages directory to `packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data.3.2.3\lib\net45`
  double click `WebMatrix.WebData.dll`
- in your **Web Project**, right click on "references" -> click "Add reference" -> click "Browse..." navigate in your packages directory to `packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data.3.2.3\lib\net45`
  double click `WebMatrix.Data.dll`

**finally:**

in your **Web.config**, remove or comment out any references to **dependentAssembly** named `WebMatrix.Data` and/or `WebMatrix.WebData`

**Re-build and run**

Comment: I've followed your instructions and now I get "The type or namespace name 'WebMatrix' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Emmanuel, please expand on this. Are you getting error during build? If so, when you double click on error, is there a using statement for `WebMatrix`?

Comment: Correct, this is a build error and it goes to the statement using WebMatrix.WebData.

Comment: I thought the problem was because the Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData was not installed properly, so I uninstalled and re-installed it (along with all the dependent packages). Now I get the following error at run time: Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=3.0.0.0..."

Comment: Scratch that last error. After I went through your instructions again with the references updated to the latest version, this error seems to be gone.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was able to remove all errors! So that was the issue all along. Still your answer was extremely useful to find the root of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was: the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData was not installed properly, so I uninstalled and re-installed it (along with all the dependent packages).

To do this, I ran:

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth  
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet  
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer 
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core 
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty 
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core  
Uninstall-Package DotNetOpenAuth.core 
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData 

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData 
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.core 
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core 
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty 
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core  
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer 
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet  
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
```

I then used the instructions from Dave Alperovich above to add the correct version of the references. Now the error is gone.