# Error downloading metadata from ASMX-webservice C#

Tags: c#, web-services, model-view-controller, asmx

I've been working on a small MVC-project which since I converted to more of an MVC-approach has stopped working.

The program consuming the web-service is a simple console-application with its own controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApplication.ServiceReference1;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
class ConsoleController
{
    ServiceReference1.WebService2SoapClient webservice = new ServiceReference1.WebService2SoapClient();

    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return webservice.GetEmployees().ToList();
    }
   }
}
```

The web-service consists of a Employee-class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace webservice
{
public class Employee
{

    public string _socialSN { get; set; }
    public string _lastName { get; set; }
    public string _firstName { get; set; }

    public Employee(string socialSN, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
        this._socialSN = socialSN;
    }
}
```

}

A data access layer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace webservice
{
public class DAL
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlCommand cmd;

    public void GetConnection()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=DB2015;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=***********");
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        GetConnection();
        con.Open();

        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SocialSN, Name, Surname FROM Employee";

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                employeeList.Add(new Employee(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            employeeList = null;
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

        reader.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();

        return employeeList;
    }
  }
}
```

A BackController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace webservice
{
class BackController
{
    DAL dal = new DAL();

    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return dal.GetEmployees();
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the webservice-code itself:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace webservice
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService2
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService2 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    BackController bcontroller = new BackController();

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return bcontroller.GetEmployees();
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to add a new service-reference to my console-application I get this error:

Error part 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5xN1.png
Error part 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG5v3.png

I cannot figure out what is wrong. It worked fine before I changed to MVC. I've tried to clean the projects, rebuild them and create them all from scratch again and just simply won't work.

Please let me know if you've got any ideas what could be wrong or if you need additional information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've upgraded some components but the code is still trying to latch onto the old version. Essentially something in your code is looking for say version 1.1.0.1 and you've got version 2.1.0.1. or something like that. You'll need to either redirect to the correct assembly in your web config or find another way to get your application to accept the newer version.

Here are some links you can check out for some tips but these can be elusive bugs to sort out.

From stackoverflow:

[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference).

that link has this one inside it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/03/25/95826.aspx

And here is an independent blogger's take on it:

http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/10/error-located-assemblys-manifest.html