# Nuget Version Mismatch Error occurs in two Solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on my Mobile Backend/Web API for my Azure Mobile Service and I got this message when I tried to debug the code. The Azure Configuration code exists in a different C# Class Library and I believe there's a version mismatch between them.

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The error comes form this line:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("photos");
```

The above lines are used to upload an image blob to my Blob Storage. I believe it's a version mismatch between the backend and the Azure Cloud APIs. What do you think this error means?

Comment: Have you upgraded the the package so it is on the same version across all projects?

Comment: That's what I can't do. When it tries to update, it says that another package is not compatible with the newer version! What is the correct method of upgrading all the packages? @deebo

Comment: What package does NuGet say is not compatible? You might not have to upgrade all packages. You can however use `Update-Package -Project ProjectName` from the package manager console to upgrade all packages in a project.  Of course, upgrading all package might lead to other problems.

Comment: as in "Update-Package -Project mywebProject" ? @ShaunLuttin

Comment: Yes. `Update-Package -Project myWebProject` or `Update-Package -Project myClassLibrary`.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I realized the problem. The Package "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration" has a version of 2.0.0.0 in my Web API Project while the Class Library has a version of "3.0.0.0". This might be the problem. Is there a way to downgrade my class library to 2.0.0.0? I dont want to upgrade since many other packages depends on the Web Project's Package. How can I downgrade?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Figured it out mate. Thank you for taking the time :)

Comment: What was the answer?

Comment: It was a version mismatch and I figured it out via reading through the list of answers you gave me. Basically the DLL version of the web project was different from the version of the Class Library it referenced and thus the clash. I had to downgrade the class library to the web project's dll version and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Half-Baked Ideas :)

**Idea 1** Within both projects, open the `packages.config` file. See whether both files reference the same version of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration`. If they differ, you can use the Package Manager Console to upgrade or downgrade one of the projects.

```
// update to a specific version of a package
Update-Package MyPackage -Version [an earlier or later version]

// update all packages within a project
Update-Package -Project ProjectName
```

**Idea 2** Within both projects, also check the `web.config > runtime > assemblyBinding` section to see whether one has a problematic `bindingRedirect` for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration`.

**Idea 3** For a more comprehensive approach, use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer. To get started, from a Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio, run `Fuslogvw.exe`.

## Helpful Links

[Troubleshooting NuGet references](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/08/26/troubleshooting-nuget-references.aspx)

[The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

[Updating All Packages](https://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20All%20Packages)

[Could not load file or assembly… NuGet Assembly Redirects](http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/11/27/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-NuGet-Assembly-Redirects.aspx)

[Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)