# Could not load file or assembly: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, entity-framework-6, xaf

I have a Dev Express web application working fine in localhost but not on the live site.

I have logged the issue with Dev Express but am also logging it here because it may be a .net issue.

I have checked the references carefully in the project and cant find any out of date references.

The error log shows

```
26.12.15 11:40:23.780   ================================================================================
26.12.15 11:40:23.796   Trace Log for /LM/W3SVC/19/ROOT-2-130955658098893565 is started
26.12.15 11:40:23.796   ================================================================================
26.12.15 11:40:23.796   System Environment
    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
    .Net Framework Versions: v2.0.50727, v4.0.30319

    CLR Version: 4.0.30319.34209
    eXpressApp Version: 15.2.4.0
Application config
    Modules=
    ErrorReportEmail=
    ErrorReportEmailServer=
    SimpleErrorReportPage=
    RichErrorReportPage=Error.aspx
    EnableDiagnosticActions=False
26.12.15 11:40:23.811   The ValueManagerType is initialized by the default value: SimpleValueManager.
26.12.15 11:40:23.811   Stack trace:
   at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ValueManager.CreateValueManager[ValueType](String key)
   at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ValueManager.GetValueManager[ValueType](String key)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.SecuritySystem.get_CurrentUserName()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Web.ErrorInfo.Initialize(Exception exception, String lastTraceEntries)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Web.ErrorHandling.ProcessApplicationError()
   at SBD.FileUploads.Web.Global.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\EShared\Dev2015\SBD.FileUploads\SBD.FileUploads.Web\Global.asax.cs:line 52
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RecordError(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

26.12.15 11:40:23.968   no context  Cannot send alert email to admin
26.12.15 11:40:23.968   no context  Error ID: afdfe65f-6113-4991-bf30-a97f1deca79b
    ================================================================================
The error occurred:

    Type:       FileLoadException
    Message:    Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.ExpressApp.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    Data:       0 entries
    Stack trace:

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.AddAssemblyDependency(String assemblyName, Boolean addDependentAssemblies)
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistrationCore(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry)
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistration(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry)
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
   at System.Web.UI.PageParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
    InnerException is null
```

I looked at [this question about winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference?rq=1)  but my problem is in webforms. I do see that some of the answers involved Dev Express. I Checked my licence file and it does not include old versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed updating an assembly reference in one of your modules.

Easiest fix is to run the DevExpress ProjectConverter (default location *C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 15.2\Components\Tools\Components*). It will fix the references in all files (and subfolders).

If you have any more trouble, the [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/support/center) is the place to ask.

Comment: I can no longer repeat the problem. I had run the project converter. I am marking your answer right because it must have been a reference issue.