# Error after deployment - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am getting an error after deployment

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Problem is both in my references and in my web.config I have webgrease version 1.3?

Where are they getting 1.0 from?

Comment: I think your quesion is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference

Comment: And to add, based on the other question I linked, the 1.0 is probably coming from the version of WebGrease that is found on your target system. Basically your software specifies that 1.3 is required but 1.0 is found, if 1.0 is acceptable then try setting "Specific Version" to false in your reference properties (which can be found by selecting the reference to WebGrease and looking in the Properties view).