# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am running published code in my local ISS than it not giving any error but when I am published this code in production server it is giving error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)". but I am not using 'Microsoft.Owin' in my application and also I not using 'Microsoft.Owin' dependency code in web.config.

I don't know what is happening.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: What actual version of MVC are you using, because it's certainly not all three you tagged the question with?

Comment: do you have a godaddy  server ?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer in server there was old code which had 'Microsoft.Owin' dependent file, I deleted all files and pasted all new published code now it is not giving any error :)