# Can not load my own file or assembly

Tags: c#

I have created two projects in one solution and the idea is that I want to have one project call a method in the other project. I have added the called project as a reference to the calling project, but when I try to run the code I get this error:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'abc,
>   Version=9.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4f047e93159395ca' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

When I paste the main method that is calling the method from the other project into the called project and only run that one it works fine. So it is likely not a problem with dependencies.

Comment: Are both projects using the same version of the .net framework?

Comment: yes both are using 4.5.2

Comment: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)??

Comment: Check your project dependencies

Comment: @txtechhelp no i don't think it is a versioning problem since i am the one who wrote the two projects.

Comment: @MatthewWhited My projects dependencies are all working because if I take the code calling the other project and put it in that project it will work fine.

Comment: Tried "Clean"ing your solution?

Comment: @mxmissile yes, unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: Do you have a version of "abc" in the GAC? `C:\Windows\assembly`

Comment: Also try removing the SNK.  It looks like you have a build order problem.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I am unable to find 'abc' in the GAC. abc is a project within the same solution

Comment: @MatthewWhited there doesnt seem to be a SNK file in my project either

Comment: Then why is it looking for a strongnamed assembly?

Comment: @MatthewWhited sorry im not too familiar with SNKs and am not sure where to find such a file

Comment: Check the signing page/sign the assembly under the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps bellow using adapting them to your needs.

1. In your Main project (the one you defined as startup project) right click on **References > Add Reference > Projects** and select the dependency.
   [image]
2. Declare the dependency project with `using` and call the method from the other project in your main program.
   [image]
3. Compile your solution, and check if the `.dll` of your dependency is in the same **bin** folder of your main application.
   [image]

Comment: I have done exactly as you have and I am still getting the same error