# WPF Application : System.Windows.Interactivity loading error

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, dll

When I am running my application I got this exception.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

So I added DLL from below location.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

After that, if I re-run the application, it is still raising the same exception. Any idea?

Comment: Is this in the main project of a wpf app?

Comment: No, I am adding kind of user control to the main project.

Comment: That dll will need to end up in the bin/debug next to your exe. Take a look in there. Is it there? If not then add the reference to whatever your main project is.

Comment: If I copy v4.5 DLL manually at exe location, while running the exe, it is asking for v4 DLL, and if I copy v4 DLL, it is asking for v4.5 DLL

Comment: You realise that is not what I suggested you do?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215054/2846483).