# Assembly Exception in ASP.Net Core Angular project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET Core Angular web application. I created this project with Visual studio 2017 angular template.  I made a very basic application with the newest dependencies:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.0.7) as NuGET
- Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.0.0) as SDK

We can build the application but when debugging , we encounter an exception as below:

> System.IO.FileLoadException   HResult=0x80131040   Message=Could not
>   load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. 
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Source=Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical

Here is the StackTrace:

StackTrace: at `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.CreateFileWatcher(String root)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, String applicationName, String contentRootPath, WebHostOptions options)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at WebApp.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in D:\Source\WebApp\Program.cs:line 21    at WebApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Source\WebApp\Program.cs:line 17`

We tried going to older versions of ASP.NET Core and back. The issue solves but next time we open the project the same exception happens. We cannot change the version of the Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.0.0) to newer versions because it is 
`blocked by the project`.

Note that we have changed the location of NugetPackages to be in specific folder (D:\Source\Library) (for the purpose of source control).

Comment: Hope you have set the `repositoryPath` for properly pointing the Nuget path

Comment: @Developer : I did not set the repositoryPath since based on documentation it is only applied to projects using packages.config. globalPackagesFolder applies only to projects using the PackageReference format. So I have set globalPackagesFolder to the NugetPath (D:\Source\Library)

Comment: have you checked this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference. It is trying to find System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.0.0, but can't find the specified version.

Comment: did you check this issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/803

Comment: Checking on the NuGet page for the [System.ComponentModel.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Primitives/) package, there isn't a 4.2.0 build. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the runtime assembly specific on execution by adding the following to your project.json, under "frameworks":

```
"System.ComponentModel.Primitives": {
  "version": "4.1.0", // or whatever version you have
  "exclude": "runtime"
},
```

This is a workaround. It is happening because the platform-specific version of the `System.ComponentModel.Primitives` is not yet released for every platform - e.g. Ubuntu. More details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9168).

Comment: .Net Core is based on msbuild, which means that it uses *.csproj instead of project.json. Anyhow, I updated .csproj to exclude runtime from the reference, but the problem remains. did you test this workaround in .net core .csproj file?