# The type initializer for ‘LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods’ threw an exception

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Specific Exception received: “Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral’ or one of its dependencies.  The located assembly’s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.”

I have two projects, one is a sort of “Proof of concept” and the exact same code works perfectly there, while the other is a large solution in which I’m adding code to one of the existing projects.

I am getting an exception in the second (failing) project when running the following line of code:

LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(baseGitHubURL + ourOrg + “/“ + ourRepo.Name, ourRepoPath + @“\” + ourRepo.Name, co);

Ahead of this code, I’ve got it printing the arguments being passed, which are as follows in the output from BOTH projects (again - identical code in each):

GitHub path: https://github.company.com/TESTING/CA4F

Filesystem path: C:\Users\User\CA4F

The creation of CloneOptions is identical in both projects with static values being used (it uses a personal access token as a username).

I am suspecting there is something wrong with how LibGit2Sharp was added to the failing project.  Note that the PROCESS was the same for both:

From NuGet console: “Install-Package LibGit2Sharp”

Both have the same version (latest, version 0.25.0).

Despite these facts, the working project has a “Dependencies” section under the project listing LibGit2Sharp, while the non functioning project does not have this section.  LibGit2Sharp WAS added as a reference to my actual project when I went to Nuget Package Manager and told it to install to ALL projects in the solution.

Another piece of information - the working project does NOT have a NuGet package for “LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries”, while the failing project does.  On a whim, I tried deleting it from the failing project, but Nuget says “Unable to uninstall ‘LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries.1.0.210’ because ‘LibGit2Sharp.0.25.0’ depends on it.”

Comment: Have you tried adding the dependency item in your working project to the non-working one?

Comment: I do not actually know how to do this.  Please understand - I did NOT explicitly add the dependency in the working project, this happened by virtue of running the exact same NuGet install command as was run in the non functioning project.  I found the following link before posting here, but it seemed more for adding a reference (despite the title) than for adding a dependency, at least from what I could tell in trying to use it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx

Could you please explain how to properly add a dependency?

Comment: You can open a project file in a text editor, then copy and paste, but if you need a proper way to add a dependency, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution)

Comment: The two projects are completely different.  Perhaps this is because of one being a single project solution and the other (failing one) being a multi project solution.  The failing one has a “packages.config”, while the working one does not.  Working project has NO reference to NativeMethods in the csproj file, while the failing one does.

On the dependency front - I was wanting to add (under my project) the visible tree that shows “Dependencies->NuGet->LibGit2Sharp (0.25.0)” that my working project has, into my failing project. The provided link is more about NuGet dependencies in general.

Comment: Is the working project just referencing the dll file locally instead of using Nuget?

Comment: No, as I mentioned in the original question, I installed using the exact same command in both projects “Install-Package LibGit2Sharp”.  Just to check, I uninstalled LibGit2Sharp from BOTH projects (in the failing project, I needed to add LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries as well).

Installing them again in both (using the identical command: “Install-Package LibGit2Sharp“) resulted in the same mismatch - the working project only lists LibGit2Sharp in Nuget Package Manager, while on the failing project, it additionally has “LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries”.

Comment: I'm kind of out of ideas, I upvoted your question. Hopefully someone comes along who has experienced this and can help, if noone comes along, I'll offer a bounty for you.

Comment: Ryan - I _really_ appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: no problem. What is the exception message you get in the failing version, it may help to find the problem? May want to update your post with that included.

Comment: Updated with the specific exception.

Comment: Seems the compiled project is either finding a version of the dll which doesn't match the requested one or none at all. It's possible you need to place the correct version onto the machine running your non working version, here is another SO post which talks about the exception message you are getting, possibly could help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: I ran the fusion log viewer and was able to determine that it found “System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral” but it has the following Error: The assembly reference did not match with the assembly definition found.

It says it is pulling the machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.Config and that GAC lookup was unsuccessful.,,,

Comment: This looks to be greatly related to the following issue:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1521

Also, for reference sake, I opened an issue in LibGit2Sharp project:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this up - I was able to resolve this by adding the following to the first configuration property group under the PropertyGroup tag in the csproj of every single project in the solution:

`<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>`

After doing that, a recompile and run allowed me to successfully call LibGit2Sharp!  :)

Note that this was the solution provided by “bording” over on the LibGit2Sharp git issues “forum”.