# ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

Full error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       C:\Users\jmatson\Source\Repos\Web-IT-Spark-CICD\SparkIdeaGenerator\Main.aspx:
>   ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)   SparkIdeaGenerator  C:\Users\jmatson\Source\Repos\Web-IT-Spark-CICD\SparkIdeaGenerator\Main.aspx    1

I had a similar issue with System.Net.Http which I think I solved by specifying the version in the Web.Config of my ASP.NET project, (non .NET Core, just standard .NET 4.6.1)... but now I get this error trying to build? It's so frustrating and I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: The error indicates that dlls present in application direction dont match the ones referenced by the project. Try reading problematic references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)