# Is there a way to check for missing assemblies at build time in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Similar question:

1. [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Let's say we have a basic .NET Standard library, which references an external DLL we got from Nuget such as `System.Data.SqlClient`.

A class relies on the external DLL to function:

```
namespace BasicLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public void Method() 
        {
            var foo = new System.Data.Sql.SqlNotificationRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

We now build our library, targeting .NET Standard 2.0.

After doing that, we create a sample Console Application (.NET Core 3.0) and we add a reference to the library we previuosly built.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bar = new BasicLibrary.Class1();
            bar.Method();
        }
    }
}
```

The code builds fine, but as expected it crashes because it is missing a reference to `System.Data.SqlClient`

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Is there a way to check at build time for missing assemblies?

Comment: Im confused how did you compile the other dll with the class (Class1) without the reference? You shouldn't have been able to compile `BasicLibrary` without the reference...

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is referenced in the `BasicLibrary` project, but not in the `ConsoleApp3` project

Comment: Is there a way to  check if i am missing `System.Data.SqlClient` in `ConsoleApp3 ` before running the program itself?

Comment: if it's the same solution add reference to Project not assembly, if it's different then create local nuget repo, push `BasicLibrary` there and add reference to `BasicLibrary` package from local nuget ...

Comment: `Is there a way to check id i am missing System.Data.SqlClient in ConsoleApp3` if nothing is using it, why check if it's missing, it doesn't make sense. If your missing a dll that you are using, it wont compile because references can't be resolved.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ `ConsoleApp3` does not _directly_  use `System.Data.SqlClient`.
However, it uses a class which uses it

Comment: If your missing the assembly, please tell me how you were able to compile `BasicLibrary`, I would love to know.

Comment: I think i was unable to get my point through.
`BasicLibrary` is successfully built, because it correctly references `System.Data.SqlClient`.
After building `BasicLibrary` to a dll file, we add it to `ConsoleApp3`, which crashes, because it does not reference `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: After a little better explanation I see what you mean. Open up your `csproj` file and add `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` that to it, rebuild and try again.

Comment: @Acerbic have you tried the above I left in a comment. I was able to replicate your issue and doing the above should resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can create targets which will do this job for you. Something like below (it checks for NUGET packages, in your case, it will be different path and library to check):

```
<Target Name="EnsureRequiredLibrariesExists" BeforeTargets="PreBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!--<ErrorText>YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE</ErrorText>-->
      <ErrorText>Please include required dlls</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.1.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.1.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />    
</Target>
```

Also,

- Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-select-the-files-to-build?view=vs-2019#example)
- and as mentioned [here](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/02/13/what-to-do-if-copy-local-works-in-vs-but.aspx/), Go through your projects in a text editor and look for references with  tags in them. Like True or False. “Private” is a synonym for “Copy Local.”