# How does one register Microsoft.Graph.Core for COM Interop

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, com-interop

Using Visual Studio 2019 16.11.11
Project: .NET Framework 4.8

Message when I build my project:
The assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe /tlb.

The following was returned is a message that says the type was registered successfully followed by a bunch of warnings and to finish up with the same RA0000 error I'd gotten before, only with a different Assembly.

I've tried deleted the Bin folder and re-building the project but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

```
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.8.4084.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.4084.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.CollectionPage 1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.ICollectionPage 1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.IEncryptedContentBearer  1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.ITokenValidable2, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.UploadResult1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.AsyncMonitor1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.BaseActionMethodRequestBuilder1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.BaseFunctionMethodRequestBuilder1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphResponse1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.IAsyncMonitor1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.DerivedTypeConverter1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.InterfaceConverter1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.LargeFileUploadTask1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
Type library exporter warning processing 'Microsoft.Graph.PageIterator1, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type. Generic classes may not be exposed to COM.
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'Microsoft.Graph.ITokenValidableExtension+<AreTokensValid>d__0`2, Microsoft.Graph.Core'. Error: Type library exporter cannot load type '<AreTokensValid>d__0`2' (error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect, Version=6.15.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: @SimonMourier  I'll take a look.  Thanks.

I've seen so many different types of workarounds and solutions to this issue, there's a good chance I may have come across this article before.  Well, maybe looking with fresh eyes will help.

Comment: @SimonMourier While the article didn't help much with my question here, it did help tremendously with another problem I encountered along the way.