# Could not load file or assembly. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. Version conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-framework-version

I am having an error when I want to run my program. The error states that it could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I have checked on my target framework and package reference which I am now using net5.0 framework for my project. But the version of System.Runtime seems to be net6.0 framework. I have checked on my System.Runtime that the version is 5.0.0.0. So obviously the version 6.0.0.0 is missing. Does anyone know how to change the version of System.Runtime to be 5.0.0.0?

Error Message
[image]

System Runtime Details
[image: System.Runtime details]

.csproj file
[image: Code Page]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i just delete my bin and obj folder and proceed to clean and rebuild my project and it works perfectly. Wasted two days for this.

Got the inspiration from this link.
[Credit to Levi Fuller's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).