# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.3.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I see below error, even though my entire solution doesn't have any reference to Nuget package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens with version 5.3.0.0
Please advise me if alteration need in any other packages ?

Error message:

System.IO.FileLoadException
HResult=0x80131040
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Source=MyMVCApp

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your solution with git clean or cleaning in visual studio?

Comment: I am just guessing maybe you have an assembly binding. However here are some considerations that helped others.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference
you could check web.config / app.config but as I said it's just a guess.