# System.BadImageFormatException due to wrong .DLL version

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm using an external Windos-DLL in my application but when I try to compile my application, I'm getting an error which states:

> An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Reference
> assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
> loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.

So I'm referencing the Windows.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll which is located on:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
> Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

I've been looking around on SA for possible solutions and I've tried a number of suggestions such as:

- Deleted the /bin and /obj folders
- Changed the Platform Target to X86
- Removed the reference and re-added the .dll again
- Checked that I'm using the correct Target Framework (which is set to 4.5.1)
- Checked that the Specific Version is set to False in the properties of the referenced .dll
- Checked that in the .csproj the correct reference was added

> ```
>  <Reference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0,
>  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,
>  processorArchitecture=MSIL">
>   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
>   <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll</HintPath>
> </Reference>
> ```

[image]

I've also verified the Details on the .dll-file itself:
[image]

So it seems the compiler found another version than the one I'm trying to use, at least that's what I can understand from a similar issue ([The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)).
The accepted solution was to run the gacutil command to add my .dll to the GAC, but when I tried to run the command I got the error:

> Failure adding assembly to the cache:   An attempt was made to load a
> program with an incorrect format.

So I'm stuck. Any other suggestions that I can try?

Comment: Yes, referencing this assembly does not make sense.  You'll have to stop doing this.  Best to focus on the unidentified reason why you decided to do this.

Comment: Try DELETING the DLL from your bin directory, then running the application without rebuilding.  You are supposed to use the "Reference" version of the DLL for building, not for actually running.  At runtime the installed .NET platform is supposed to provide the platform-specific version.  It seems like a mistake to have `Copy Local=true` like your reference does.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I just reinstalled the System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime again from NuGet and now it's working.